Postgres - TypeError: tabulate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'colalign'
I have problem in Postgres 16.2 with plpython procedure and library tabulate.
I created procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dpl.__test_tabulate()
LANGUAGE plpython3u AS $plpy$
from tabulate import tabulate
plpy.info('%s' % tabulate([["one", "two"], ["three", "four"]], colalign=("right",)))
$plpy$;

But when I run it in psql, I get the error:
database=# CALL dpl.__test_tabulate();
ERROR:  TypeError: tabulate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'colalign'
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "__test_tabulate", line 4, in <module>
    plpy.info('%s' % tabulate([["one", "two"], ["three", "four"]], colalign=("right",)))
PL/Python procedure "__test_tabulate"
database=#

The my postgres runs on RHEL 8.9.
On the RHEL is Python 3.9 installed (with 3.6 together).
When I run this procedure in Python 3.9, it works:
# python
Python 3.9.18 (main, Sep 22 2023, 18:24:59)
[GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-20)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tabulate import tabulate
>>> print(tabulate([["one", "two"], ["three", "four"]], colalign=("right",)))
-----  ----
  one  two
three  four
-----  ----

But Postgres 16.2 use python 3.6, and there the procedure does not work. And when I run the procedure in RHEL python 3.6, it does not works too.
How do I force Postgres to use python 3.9 instead of 3.6 version?
postgres@server:/var/lib/pgsql # python3 -V
Python 3.9.18

postgres@server:/var/lib/pgsql # pip show tabulate
Name: tabulate
Version: 0.9.0
Summary: Pretty-print tabular data
Home-page:
Author:
Author-email: Sergey Astanin <s.astanin@gmail.com>
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: apache-airflow

postgres@server:/var/lib/pgsql # psql -d database
psql (16.2)
Type "help" for help.

database=# select pyver();
                  pyver
-----------------------------------------
 3.6.8 (default, Jan  5 2024, 09:14:44) +
 [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-20)]
(1 row)

database=#

The problem was found after upgrade from version 13.5 to new version 16.2. Setup of the upgrade>

was installed new server with RedHat 8.9 (Python 3.9)
was installed Postgres binaries (version 13.5) and created user postgres
then was connected disk with Postgres databases (version 13.5) from old server
the DB's was started on new server
next step was installation of Postgres 16.2
then was start with upgrade of DB's to new Postgres version via this command:

time /usr/pgsql-16/bin/pg_upgrade --jobs=16 -d /postgres/pgsql/database/data13 -D /postgres/pgsql/database/data16 -b /usr/pgsql-13/bin/ -B /usr/pgsql-16/bin/ --link


after upgrade runs DB's on new version

The main DB has 70TB size.
Installation packages was downloaded from this repository:
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/16/redhat/rhel-8.9-ppc64le/

Did you install Postgres and plpython3u from packages or did you compile them yourself?

Is installed from the packages.


What does python3 -V return? 2) What is the tabulate version installed for Python 3.6?


python3 -V
Python 3.9.18

pip show tabulate
Name: tabulate
Version: 0.9.0
Summary: Pretty-print tabular data
Home-page:
Author:
Author-email: Sergey Astanin s.astanin@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: apache-airflow

In postgres is Python version:
amd1=# select pyver();
pyver
3.6.8 (default, Jan  5 2024, 09:14:44) +
[GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-20)]
(1 row)
amd1=# \q

On the next server I have PostgreSQL version 13.5 with the same version of Python (function pyver() show the same version).
On the actual server is PostgreSQL 16.2 - but it was upgraded from version 13.5.
It seems python in Postgres was not upgraded.


Include the information in your question text not the comments, makes it easier for folks to see. 2) The request was for the tabulate version installed for Python 3.6, you provided the version for Python 3.9. 3) The plpython3u Python version remains the same because that is the version that is being compiled against when building the packages. 4) Where are you getting the packages from the Red Hat repo or the PGDG repos. Add answers as update to question text.


In another forum where I asked about my problem, I received information that RHEL 8 has Python 3.6 by default.
That's enough of an answer for me. I was worried that I had made a mistake during the upgrade.
Now I know I didn't make a mistake during the upgrade.
One way to change the Python used is to recompile plpython3u. But experts strongly do not recommend this.
So the only possibility is to upgrade RHEL to version 9. But I can do that when Postgres 16 is also available for the ppc64le platform.
So thank you all.
